# Date field is not displayed when DateFormat is dd.MM.yyyy and dd is bigger than 12

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, date-format

In my view model i have several DateTime fields. I've decorated them with DisplayFormat attribute to give them date time format:

```
 public class MyModel{
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
   public DateTime? ReceivedDate{get;set;}
   //omitted for brevity
 }
```

This is the View:

```
 <div>@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.ReceivedDate)</div>
```

Now when date is say 12 July 1985, it'll display 07.12.1985 (Day and month swapped). But if I set date to for example 13 July 1985 , it'll be just blank. So apparently MVC tries to match the entered date to some other format.

P.S. I first insert the model to database and then read the recently added model on another view.

Comment: I tried, but can't reproduce this.  The format applies without the behavior you described.  Can you please check - what is the value of `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`?  Perhaps that is influencing things here.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Where do you want me to check for it. I have nowhere with that specified

Comment: Anywhere will work.  You can just put it in the view.

Comment: Hah, you mean to output it. It shows en-US.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.  I was just checking.  Culture can influence the behavior of `DateTime` formatting.  But I don't think that's the case here.  I tried the exact code you gave and it is working for me.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem that caused this issue. In my web.config file, there was the following entry:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="auto:en-US" uiCulture="auto:en-US" />
</system.web>
```

So this was setting the current culture to US. After removing that entry the problem got solved. BTW, you can just set your desired culture instead of removing too.